# Ionic Framework for Mobile WEBSITE

Tags: angularjs, html, mobile, ionic-framework, mobile-website

I want to use Ionic Framework for my mobile **website**. 
I wonder that is there any risk for run Ionic Framework on mobile browsers.
I'll only use framework's CSS and JS which includes modals, popups, menus etc.

I built a prototype and I tested it on all versions of iPhone and 2-3 versions of Samsung. I haven't seen any problem on these devices. But I want to learn all risks before I start to real project which includes static pages and quotation steps. I'll use UI router by using HTML5 pushstate.

To learn your opinions, makes me more confident.

Thanks in advance.

Kindest...

Comment: Your mobile website may not running if client have slow mobile connection to load ionic JS and CSS, especially angular.

Comment: Thank you for response @justmyfreak. But we do not consider the connection speeds. As our reports, clients connections are mostly 3g. I'm only concerned about Ionic's technical effects on mobile browsers.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain caveats to this:
1. Ionic doesn't have a web server, and its testing server uses UIWebview and will not allow for POST requests.
2. Ionic is more optimized for app that is resident on the device. There are certain capabilities (ngCordova plugins for camera...etc.) that won't be available on mobile web.

Your scenario ("framework's CSS and JS which includes modals, popups, menus etc.") - should be fine, since you're only using functionality within Webview. You'd have to build a custom JS library that would only include presentation layer features.